# LINQ/C#: Add record isnt working for some reason

Tags: c#, linq, insert

ok here's the code im using which every site ive looked at says is right, but its not working. Im trying to insert the fields from the object into the table called 'employees' in my sql database. The object's fields match the fields in the database exactly:

```
myDatabaseDataContext db = new myDatabaseDataContext();
Emps newGuy = new Emps
{
     FirstName = txtFirstName.Text
     LastName = txtLastName.Text
};

db.employees.InsertOnSubmit(newGuy);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

The error it is giving me is "cannot convert TrainingDatabase.Emps to TrainingDatabase.employee" and another error that says db.employees.InsertOnSubmit(newGuy) has some invalid arguements.

Comment: Working is poor choice of words here, the fact that the code does not even compile, precludes it from even working in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at what `db.employees` contains.

I'm guessing its an `Table<Employee>`, which does not match what you are trying to insert. (`Emps`)

Are you trying to insert a single or collection of employees?

Based purely on the error you have given, your code should be:

```
Employee newGuy = new Employee
{
     FirstName = txtFirstName.Text
     LastName = txtLastName.Text
};
```

Not `Emps`.

Comment: oh snap, you know what. I was using an instance of a class Emps that I made... thanks lol

Comment: @Sinaesthetic - no worries :) I have done same mistake many times. Sometimes you just need another set of eyes to point out your mistake. Don't forget to tick the correct answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

If your table name is Employee, then your object must me like

```
myDatabaseDataContext db = new myDatabaseDataContext();


Employee emp = new Employee();

emp.FirstName = blabla;
emp.LastName = blabla;

db.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(emp);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Should always check for duplicate answers before posting the same one. Keeps the thread cleaner.

Comment: First, I didnt see 1 answer posted, load new answer notification. Second, thread has just two answer, its not lookin dirty, because your answer and my answer are different usage for syntax example. Why you are making this a problem? As you see I'm not a newbie. I didnt delete my answer, because as I said your and my answer are different usage of syntax example